# Saving items from Scrapyd to Amazon S3 using Feed Exporter

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy, scrapyd

Using Scrapy with amazon S3 is fairly simple, you set:

- FEED_URI = 's3://MYBUCKET/feeds/%(name)s/%(time)s.jl'
- FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'
- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = [access key]
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  = [secret key]

and everything works just fine.

But Scrapyd seems to override that setting and saves the items on the server (with a link in the web site)

Adding the "items_dir =" setting doesn't seem to change anything.

What kind of setting makes it work?

EDIT: Extra info that might be relevant - we are using Scrapy-Heroku.

Comment: do you see anything in scrapyd logs? Does it save items on S3 if you run your crawler directly via `scrapy crawl`? How did you tell scrapyd where your project `settings` file is?

Comment: Nothing in the logs as far as I can see. It does save to S3 when I do `scrapy crawl` (This tells me the S3 configuration is fine) and I just put the settings in the default location (I know it reads it well because I have the `application` setting there - which works fine)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. 
Removing the  items_dir= from scrapyd.conf file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `items_dir` property to an empty value like this:

```
[scrapyd]
items_dir=
```

It seems that when that property is set, takes precedence over the configured exported. See http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html for more information.