# How to upload crawled data from Scrapy to Amazon S3 as csv or json?

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, web-scraping, scrapy

What are the steps to upload the crawled data from Scrapy to the Amazon s3 as a csv/jsonl/json file? All i could find from the internet was to upload scraped images to the s3 bucket.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04,
and i have installed boto by the command,

```
pip install boto
```

I have added the following lines to settings.py. Can anyone explain the other changes i have to make.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'access key id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'access key'


FEED_URI = 'bucket path'
FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = None
FEED_STORE_EMPTY = False
FEED_STORAGES = {}
FEED_STORAGES_BASE = { 
'': None,
'file': None,
'stdout': None,
's3': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.S3FeedStorage',
'ftp': None,
}
FEED_EXPORTERS = {}
FEED_EXPORTERS_BASE = {
    'json': None,
    'jsonlines': None,
    'jl': None,
    'csv': None,
    'xml': None,
    'marshal': None,
    'pickle': None,
}
```

**Edit 1 :**  When i configure all the above and run `scrapy crawl spider`,
I get the following error after the crawled results.

```
2016-08-08 10:57:03 [scrapy] ERROR: Error storing csv feed (200 items) in: s3: myBucket/crawl.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 246, in inContext
result = inContext.theWork()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 262, in <lambda>
inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
return func(*args,**kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 123, in _store_in_thread
key.set_contents_from_file(file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1293, in set_contents_from_file
chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 750, in send_file
chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 951, in _send_file_internal
query_args=query_args
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 656, in make_request
auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
path = '/' + bucket
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Comment: Try it and come back with the problems you face while doing it

Comment: I have configured settings as shown above and executed the program, but it leaves no error and still doesn't show up in the s3 bucket. i refereed the following link  [link]_(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955723/saving-items-from-scrapyd-to-amazon-s3-using-feed-exporter)_

Comment: Better refer to the docs http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-s3

Comment: Can you do one thing break it into steps: There is `scrapy signal` download the file in `json` or `csv` and use `s3cli` or `aws cli` push data into `s3` using some bash script and then at the end it deletes the file on your local system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the following line into `settings.py` file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINE = {
'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 1
}
```

along with the S3 credentials mentioned earlier.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'access key id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'access key'

FEED_URI='s3://bucket/folder/filename.json'
```

Thank you guys for your guidance.

Comment: Hi, could you  show how you write your  `S3FilesStore`?

Answer (score 10):

**As of 2021** this task has become much easier.

- `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` are deprecated and were moved
  inside a new setting called `FEEDS`.
- There is no need to define a custom item pipeline inside `settings.py`.
- You must have `botocore` installed for this to work.

This is what you have to add to `settings.py`:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your_access_key_id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your_secret_access_key'

FEEDS = {
    's3://your-bucket/path-to-data/%(name)s/data.json': {
        'format': 'json',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'store_empty': False,
        'indent': 4,
    }
}
```

A list of all available options can be reviewed in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds).

If you also want to store files or images in s3, then you need to specify an item pipeline and a storage variable in `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1  # For images, Pillow must be installed
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 2  # For files
}

IMAGES_STORE = 's3://your-bucket/path_to_images_dir/'
FILES_STORE = 's3://your-bucket/path_to_files_dir/'
```

Comment: I get botocore error when trying to upload without specifying region. If someone meets the same problem, add `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` to your env var.

Answer (score 6):

I've decided to answers Mil0R3 comment on Abhishek K answer with the code snippet that worked for me.

in settings.py you need to add the following code:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''

# You need to have both variables FEED_URI and S3PIPELINE_URL set to the same
# file or this code will not work.
FEED_URI = 's3://{bucket}/{file_name}.jsonl'
S3PIPELINE_URL = FEED_URI
FEED_FORMAT = 'jsonlines'

# project_folder refers to the folder that both pipelines.py and settings.py are in
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    '{project_folder}.pipelines.S3Pipeline': 1,
}
```

Inside the pipelines.py you need to add the following object. The github project this is copied and pasted from can be found here: https://github.com/orangain/scrapy-s3pipeline

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


from io import BytesIO
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from datetime import datetime
import gzip

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

from scrapy.exporters import JsonLinesItemExporter

class S3Pipeline:
    """
    Scrapy pipeline to store items into S3 bucket with JSONLines format.
    Unlike FeedExporter, the pipeline has the following features:
    * The pipeline stores items by chunk.
    * Support GZip compression.
    """

    def __init__(self, settings, stats):
        self.stats = stats

        url = settings['S3PIPELINE_URL']
        o = urlparse(url)
        self.bucket_name = o.hostname
        self.object_key_template = o.path[1:]  # Remove the first '/'

        self.max_chunk_size = settings.getint('S3PIPELINE_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE', 100)
        self.use_gzip = settings.getbool('S3PIPELINE_GZIP', url.endswith('.gz'))

        self.s3 = boto3.client(
            's3',
            region_name=settings['AWS_REGION_NAME'], use_ssl=settings['AWS_USE_SSL'],
            verify=settings['AWS_VERIFY'], endpoint_url=settings['AWS_ENDPOINT_URL'],
            aws_access_key_id=settings['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
            aws_secret_access_key=settings['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
        self.items = []
        self.chunk_number = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings, crawler.stats)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """
        Process single item. Add item to items and then upload to S3 if size of items
        >= max_chunk_size.
        """
        self.items.append(item)
        if len(self.items) >= self.max_chunk_size:
            self._upload_chunk(spider)

        return item

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        """
        Callback function when spider is open.
        """
        # Store timestamp to replace {time} in S3PIPELINE_URL
        self.ts = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat().replace(':', '-')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        """
        Callback function when spider is closed.
        """
        # Upload remained items to S3.
        self._upload_chunk(spider)

    def _upload_chunk(self, spider):
        """
        Do upload items to S3.
        """

        if not self.items:
            return  # Do nothing when items is empty.

        f = self._make_fileobj()

        # Build object key by replacing variables in object key template.
        object_key = self.object_key_template.format(**self._get_uri_params(spider))

        try:
            self.s3.upload_fileobj(f, self.bucket_name, object_key)
        except ClientError:
            self.stats.inc_value('pipeline/s3/fail')
            raise
        else:
            self.stats.inc_value('pipeline/s3/success')
        finally:
            # Prepare for the next chunk
            self.chunk_number += len(self.items)
            self.items = []

    def _get_uri_params(self, spider):
        params = {}
        for key in dir(spider):
            params[key] = getattr(spider, key)

        params['chunk'] = self.chunk_number
        params['time'] = self.ts
        return params

    def _make_fileobj(self):
        """
        Build file object from items.
        """

        bio = BytesIO()
        f = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=bio) if self.use_gzip else bio

        # Build file object using ItemExporter
        exporter = JsonLinesItemExporter(f)
        exporter.start_exporting()
        for item in self.items:
            exporter.export_item(item)
        exporter.finish_exporting()

        if f is not bio:
            f.close()  # Close the file if GzipFile

        # Seek to the top of file to be read later
        bio.seek(0)

        return bio
```

Special Notes:

I needed to remove some data inside the OP's settings.py file for this Pipeline to work correctly. All of this will need to be removed

```
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = None
FEED_STORE_EMPTY = False
FEED_STORAGES = {}
FEED_STORAGES_BASE = { 
'': None,
'file': None,
'stdout': None,
's3': 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.S3FeedStorage',
'ftp': None,
}
FEED_EXPORTERS = {}
FEED_EXPORTERS_BASE = {
    'json': None,
    'jsonlines': None,
    'jl': None,
    'csv': None,
    'xml': None,
    'marshal': None,
    'pickle': None,
}
```

Also, be sure to have S3PIPELINE_URL variable equal to FEED_URI

Either, not removing the above info from settings.py or not having the two above variables set to each other will result in a jsonl file showing up inside your S3 bucket, but with multiple copies of only a single item added. I have no idea why that happens, though...

This took me a few hours to figure out, so I hope it saves someone some time.